# Settings up git and managing file ownership on platform with several users

Tags: git

We have a platform on which multiple people can be working on the same packages. As such we would like to maintain each persons individual git credentials so it's not just one person's sshkey and one person all over the commit history.

We had an idea that there could be users such that:

- `platform_name` is the main user, and the user with ownership over all the files. This is also the user people use to make changes on the system
- `firstname_lastname` for each individual, where this user only has the git credentials. Such that when the person `firstname lastname` wants to commit, they do it from their user

This becomes difficult though, because git actions generally change the file ownership. Is there a workaround or is there a better system for managing something like this?

Answer (score 2):

> As such we would like to maintain each persons individual git credentials so it's not just one person's sshkey and one person all over the commit history.

Yes, that's the standard use case: git is a distributed version control system. Everybody works on their own, local copy. Cooperation happens by them "pushing" changes upstream to a shared repository, owned not by the individual contributor.

> Is there a workaround or is there a better system for managing something like this?

Do it like gitolite, github, gitlab, gitea/forgejo, … do it out of the box!

Each user, as usual, has their own user account on their own machine – nothing about that changes.

For the central git repository, you do the following: There's a single Unix user (typically, named `git`). You set up your SSH server to forward any connection for that user to a daemon that knows the individual contributors – and tells them apart by the SSH key they authenticate with.

That's relatively easily set up: I don't know which kind of UNIX system you're on, but for me, all I had to do (Fedora F38, same should apply to RedHat/Alma/Rocky/CentOS/OpenSUSE…) was [install `podman`](https://podman.io/getting-started/installation), make sure I'm allowed to run containers (`usermod --add-subuids 100000-165535 --add-subgids 100000-165535 YOURUSERNAMEHERE` does that), and then run

```bash
podman volume create forgejo-config
podman volume create forgejo-data
podman run \
   -it \
   -p 3000:3000 -p 2222:2222 \
   -v forgejo-config:/etc/gitea \
   -v forgejo-data:/var/lib/gitea \
   --name forgejo \
   codeberg.org/forgejo/forgejo:1.18.3-1-rootless
```

Steer your browser to http://localhost:3000 afterwards, just accept the defaults, register a new user, which will become the admin. Each of your git users also registers a new user on that same interface. It's easy!

They go to "settings" in the web UI, and upload their public ssh key.

From there on, they can create new repos in their own namespace, or access repos to which they have gotten access privileges by the individual repo maintainer, through things like

```
git clone ssh://git@localhost:2222/projectowner/project
```

(of course, replace `localhost` by the name of your machine if you're not on the same machine, and replace `projectowner` by, well, the owning user or project name, and `project` by the name of the repository.)

Comment: I should note, perhaps it was a bit unclear in the original, that the vast majority of our work happens on our own computers, is pushed, and then pulled on the platform. This setup is more to address the occasional changes that need to be made at a moments notice which likely will be on the system

Comment: I have a question to how this works, so the platform will have only one user (`git`). But when you say "in their own namespace" I'm not entirely sure what that means, ideally for us we'll have a workspace (`/home/git/platform_ws`) which houses everything we need to build.

Also regarding the repos, these are all hosted in our git organization, so the sharing or access aspect isn't really a problem here either. I'm just trying to understand how this solution would work for us.

Comment: @MortenNissov I don't quite understand your explanation about changes made at a moment's notice– urgent changes would just happen the same way, right?

Comment: @MortenNissov "SSH server […] forward any connection for that user to a daemon that knows the individual contributors – and tells them apart by the SSH key they authenticate with." <-- that's the trick. The repository is owned by the git user, and the individual users don't directly interact with it, but through a daemon who can tell them apart (by their public keys) although they all authenticate as user "git".

Comment: If we're out in the field doing deployment testing it is not necessarily with internet access, therefore changes would likely be made on the platform through the ssh.

That's what I mean, there's normal office work (changes made on personal computers) and for some reason changes made directly on the platform. Does that make sense?

Comment: whatever builds your software would typically work on a clean checkout of the code – for example, it's typical that continuos integration runs on every push to set of branches, kicking off a checkout, build, and return of success. If individual developers need to have individual builds locally or on some build machine, the just git fetch/ checkout the state from the git server.

Comment: @MortenNissov sure, that makes sense, but:

Comment: What you do in the field happens on some machine. You commit changes there to the local git. In git, you always strive to work on a local checkout! You change, git commit, git push, if necessary that automatically (or you manually) triggers a rebuild.

Comment: Our procedures may not be the "correct" way to do this, but it's just what happens in our group. So I'm just trying to ensure this would work well as group habits are harder to change :)

Unrelated our platforms are typically running some ubuntu or ubuntu derivative, so I assume this should be supported.

Comment: I don't understand what you do in your group – but it seems this has nothing to do with "correct" usage, more with "safe and efficient" usage :) But I understand this: person is out in the field, finds a bug, needs to fix bug on software running somewhere else "A" (a server, I guess?). Person uses SSH to log into "A" and make ad-hoc change to git repository that runs the software? (I think it would greatly help communication if you could actually spell out the usage scenario here, most probably with a "paper napkin + sharpie + phone camera"-style drawing illustrating who does what where.)

Comment: (that's a bit of the problem if you're using some system in surprising ways that weren't intended: You will need to explain to strangers on the internet who want to help what you are doing from the ground up)

Answer (score -2):

#### To setting up the git in linux and give acces to your pc to push or pull your repositary and give permission so you need to creat SSH key for git.

**just follow these steps:**

**write the command(give your eamil on example email):**

ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C emailexample@gmail.com

**write 2nd command**

eval "$(ssh -agent -s)"

**3rd command (if file not present create file)**

~/.ssh/config

touch ~/.ssh/config

**4th command open the config file on vim editor using this command**

vim ~/.ssh/config

**type these commands in file :**

Host *

```
AddKeysToAgent yes  

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

**<now save the file with command**

**Run this command**

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub

.SSH -T git@github.com

or

ssh -T git@github.com

congurats you have done

Comment: Welcome to U&L. The OP asks "How do I set up git in a specific way". Your answer is "How to create SSH keys and access github using the newly created keys". There's no indication OP wouldn't know how to do that, so could you please edit your answer to explain how exactly it addresses the question asked?